# JAVA Spark job Tungsten error when using javaRDD to Dataframe.

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to create a dataframe using two different methods.

**Environment** :Spark 1.6.1

**Method1 :**

```
JavaRDD<String> javardd = some function.  <This will return json strings>
DataFrame df1= hiveCtx.read().json(javardd)
```

**Method2:**

```
 JavaRDD<String> javardd = some function; <This will return json strings>
 javardd.saveAsTextFile(path);
 DataFrame df1= hiveCtx.read().json(path);
```

With the DataFrame df1 we are doing joins and other complex function

With **Method2**  everything works perfectly fine.

However **Method1** throws multiple errors. 
Some times it is

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

some times we get

```
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package: execute, tree:
TungstenAggregate(key=[xxxxx
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything incorrect.

*Note*: No change in data has been done. It is the same data. 
No change in lower part of the code, apart from what is mentioned. 
No change in environment.